# How do I create a canvas the size of the window resolution without scaling?

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, web-applications, canvas

I would like to create a 2d space game which can be played as a web app on several devices such as pc, iphone, android, and ipad.  I would like to detect screen resolutions automatically and adjust the canvas resolution to match.  As the resolution changes from device to device I plan to show more or less of the map.  I will adjust space ship sizes programmatically if need be.  Any ideas on how I can do this?  I'm new to javascript and web development.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery plug-in called [Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/2009/02/supersized-full-screen-backgroundslideshow-jquery-plugin/) that does exactly what you're asking for.  It gives you a full screen image background, no matter what size the screen is.  If you can use jQuery this is one way to go.